# How do I implement a list of lists which extends Comparable?

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, generic-list, comparable

I try to make a generic linked list.

The node of this linked list using `<T extends Comparable <T>>`. But when I use

```
LList<LList<Integer>> linkedlist = new LList<LList<Integer>>();
```

to create a new instance, there is an error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Bound mismatch: The type LList<Integer> is not a valid substitute
   for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<T>> of the type LList<T>
- Bound mismatch: The type LList<Integer> is not a valid substitute
   for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<T>> of the type
```

How do I fix this?

---

Node class:

```
public class Node <T extends Comparable <T>> {

// Members:
public T data;
public Node <T> next;
// Methods:
public Node () {
    data =null;
    next = null;
}
public Node (T data) {
    this.data = data;
    next = null;
}
}
```

LList class:

```
public class LList <T extends Comparable <T>> {

// Members:
public Node <T> head;
// Methods:
public LList () {
    head = null;
}

// Add node.
public void addNode (T data) {
    if (head == null) {
        head = new Node <T> (data);
        return;
    }
    Node <T> newNode = new Node <T> (data);
    Node <T> tempNode = head;
    while (tempNode.next != null) tempNode = tempNode.next;
    tempNode.next = newNode;
}

// Show linked list.
public void showLLForInteger () {
    if (head == null) return;
    Node <T> tempNode = head;
    while (tempNode != null) {
        System.out.print(String.format("%-6d", tempNode.data));
        tempNode = tempNode.next;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LList<T extends Comparable>
```

so `LList` accepts only classes that extends Comparable as type parameter.

```
LList <LList<Integer>> subArrsList = new LList <LList<Integer>>();
```

in this statement you are giving `LList<Integer>` class as type parameter. `LList<Integer>` does not extend `Comparable`. 
Integer extends comparable but you are not using the Integer class as type parameter, You are using LList which does not extends Comparable.

So you are getting an error.

Change your `LList` class as follows:

```
public class LList <T extends Comparable <T>> implements Comparable<LList<T>>{
    @Override public int compareTo(LList<T> list) {
        //to do
    }
...// your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and could tell me how to deal with this problem? I try to let class LList extends Comparable, but can not.

Comment: You should not use raw types. You are using the raw type `Comparable` in the first example, and the raw type `LList` in the last.

Comment: @newacct there is no raw type used in my answer.

Comment: "`LList<T extends Comparable>`" <-- `Comparable` is a raw type. `Comparable` is a generic type and you didn't put type arguments on it.

Comment: "`public class LList <T extends Comparable <T>> implements Comparable<LList>`" <-- the `LList` at the end is a raw type. `LList` is a generic type and you didn't put type arguments on it.

Comment: First line of code is copied from the question to show what is wrong with it.

I corrected the other one.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why are you requiring that `T extends Comparable<T>`? You do not seem to be using that anywhere.
2. Since you require that `T extends Comparable<T>`, that means the parameter of the list must be comparable to itself. `LList<LList<Integer>>` doesn't work because `LList<Integer>` is not comparable to itself (it does not extend `Comparable<LList<Integer>>`). Are you sure you don't just want `LList<Integer>`?